# regsvr32 fails with error code 80040111 when trying to register a .dll built on another machine

Tags: .net-core, com, solidworks, regsvr32

I have created an add-in for SolidWorks in C# using `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>`. Building (with `dotnet build`) produces a `MyAddin.dll` as well as a `MyAddin.comhost.dll`.

In order to register the add-in, I can run (with admin permissions):

```
regsvr32 MyAddin.comhost.dll
```

This makes the add-in usable in SolidWorks.

However, if I share the build output files with my coworker and he tries to register the .dll in the same way, a messagebox appears that says:

```
The module "MyAddin.comhost.dll" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80040111.

For more information about this problem, search online using the error code as a search term.
```

When he builds the project on his machine and shares it with me, I get the same error.

We both run `regsvr32` with admin permissions.

The main contents of my project's `.csproj` file is:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
    <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>
    <XCadRegDll>false</XCadRegDll>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <nullable>enable</nullable>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <NoWarn>NU1701,CS8002</NoWarn>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>false</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

Again, either of us can register the .dll just fine if we build it on our own machines. It is only when we try to register the .dll built by the other that we get the error. It is important that we can register on other machines because we need to be able to make the add-in available to other people at our company who cannot build it themselves.

Is there some requirement for .dll's passed to `regsvr32` that is not fulfilled when we use files built on another machine? Is there a different way do this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you copy both DLLs from the other computer?

Comment: The error code is so strange that it is almost certainly [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/636f89d78efeda58e938534f9b1da1981e6c8575/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/Internal/Runtime/InteropServices/ComActivator.cs#L390).  In other words, it can no longer find the [ComVisible] class back in the assembly.  Very strange.  One thing stands out, [wrong SDK](https://xcad.xarial.com/extensions/registering/).  Hmm.

Comment: Yeah, from @HansPassant 's suggestion, I'd check to be sure you define Guid's for your modules and COM exported object. Also, make sure you define ProgIds although that is a very much less likely (probably zero) scenario for the problem...but it is always good practice. If you don't assign Guids, the compiler or other .NET component will assign one and they will be different on the two machines.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears if you only copy `MyAddin.comhost.dll` and not `MyAddin.dll`. It actually means that `MyAddin.dll` (where the `[ComVisible]` Classes reside) is missing.