# .NET6: registering COM DLL with regsvr32 results in 80040111

Tags: c#, com, credential-providers

I'm playing around with CredentialProviders for Win10/11, following Steve Syfuh's [blog post](https://syfuhs.net/2017/10/15/creating-custom-windows-credential-providers-in-net/) and [repo](https://github.com/SteveSyfuhs/CredProvider.NET). Using the repo as is (.net framework 4.6.1) works nicely, but I'd like to do it in .net6.

I've read [the docs about COM for .net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com) and tried to follow, but whatever I do, I get the following error:

> The module [myproject].comhost.dll was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80040111.

My steps were:

- put `[ComVisible(true)]` and unique GUIDs to the public classes that should be reachable (namely `CredentialProvider`, `CredentialView`, `CredentialProviderCredential`)
- edit `.csproj` file and add `<EnableComHosting>True</EnableComHosting>`
- run the `midl` tool to get `credentialprovider.tlb` and add it to the `.csproj` file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <ComHostTypeLibrary Include="..\interop\credentialprovider.tlb" Id="1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

- elevate the `cmd` to run `regsvr32 [myproject].comhost.dll` and get the error above

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610909/regsvr32-fails-with-error-code-80040111-when-trying-to-register-a-dll-built-on) with similar content (but I cannot run it on my machine, and the [myproject].dll is right next to the comhost one), I tried suggestions in Hans Passant's [link](https://xcad.xarial.com/extensions/registering/), but all in vain.

Does anyone has any suggestions as to what could be the issue, please?

I guess I can still do it in .net framework 4.8 (that again works), but I'd like to meddle with it a bit and I'd like to stick to newest version of .net (and also some of the packages I'd like to use don't support framework anymore).

Comment: I mention this in my question - I've tried suggestions there (even from your comment :) ), but could not get it working. I try to register it from the build folder, so both DLLs are there; from an elevated cmd; and I've tried to use the Solidworks advice. Nope :(

Comment: It should be possible with .NET Core/5/6 but devil hides in details. You should post a full reproducible sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you building `Any CPU`? You must force to build both separate 32 and 64-bit versions (`Win32` and `x64`). 64-bit version must be registered usung `C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe` and 32-bit version using `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe`

Comment: [Sorry for the delay, swamped at work...] I started from scratch, recreating just the bare bones project to share on GitHub (basically just Syfuhs' code moved to .net6), and somehow when I really started from scratch - create a .net6 solution, copy classes manually there and correct some of the errors VS complained about - now it suddenly works. At least the COM registration part, there is something else wrong (does not appear in login options; but the logger works, so I'll hopefully figure it out).
Anyway, thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after checking it from time to time, I figured it out. My only issue was that I renamed the original `CredProvider.Net.Interop2.dll` to `Interop2.dll`. Once I renamed the DLL back to its original name, it started to work like a charm again.

Weird though, since in the project file I anyway indicated the right path:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="CredProvider.NET.Interop2">
    <HintPath>..\midl\Interop2.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

But I'll leave it to wiser men than I am. (And for my project, I'll recreate the DLL anyway together with a suitable name.)

In the end, I share the results, in case someone else wants to play with Credential Providers in current C# versions: [CredentialProvider.Net6](https://github.com/zajicovo/CredentialProvider.Net6). I also corrected all the VS warnings that annoyed me. There are a few bugs though inherited from the original repo, but I'll leave them be - finding and correcting them is relatively easy and create a nice exercise to really understand credential providers :-)